# How to write the type signature of a template function in Chapel

Tags: function, templates, types, chapel

In trying to write an arithmetic mean function, it is perhaps better to write one template function rather than two type specific functions. One can write:

`proc mean(data: [?] ?T): real`

but how to restrict T to being `int` or `real`.

Also is it possible to define an array that can have either `int` or `real` data, i.e. is there a way of expressing union types for array contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To restrict the type of T to `int` or `real` types of any size you can add a `where` clause to the function definition:

```
proc mean(data: [] ?T): real where isIntType(T) || isRealType(T) { ... }
```

The `isIntType` and `isRealType` functions are defined in the Types module: http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/modules/standard/Types.html

Chapel supports safe unions and arrays of unions.  Unions are described in section 17 of the Chapel language specification: http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/_downloads/chapelLanguageSpec.pdf

```
union IntOrReal {
  var i: int;
  var r: real;
}

var intRealArray: [1..2] IntOrReal;
intRealArray[1].i = 1;
intRealArray[2].r = 2.0;
```

Comment: Fairly analogous to D template constraints https://dlang.org/concepts.html that makes things conceptually straightforward. If using the IntOrReal how to add a where constraint to augment isIntType and isRealType?

Comment: The where clause can contain anything that evaluates to a boolean param (compile time constant).  You can use the equality operator on types to compare T to any type: `where isIntType(T) || isRealType(T) || T == IntOrReal`.

Comment: Is there a syntax for initialising the whole array of union in one go?

Comment: You can use promotion on the field accessors (section 25.4 in the Chapel spec) to assign e.g. to all of the integer fields `intRealArray.i = 1;`.

Comment: Good to know for initializing all element to a given value, whole array operations. What about having a set of disparate values? (I want to avoid having to use assignment of individual entries, I want something like other languages: var x = [0, 4.7, 3, 3, 5.6];

Comment: I'm not aware of a one-liner way to do an initialization like that.  A few
somewhat less succinct ways:

1. Return initialized unions from a function.

`proc f(val) {
  var x: IntOrReal;
  if val.type == int then
    x.i = val;
  else if val.type == real then
    x.r = val;
  else
    compilerError("unhandled type initializing IntOrReal");
  return x;
}
var intOrRealArray: [1..5] IntOrReal = [f(0), f(4.7), f(3), f(3), f(5.6)];`

Comment: 2. Use a param for loop and a temporary tuple.

`var intOrRealArray: [1..5] IntOrReal;
var tupleTmp = (0, 4.7, 3, 3, 5.6);

for param i in 1..5 {
  if tupleTmp(i).type == int {
    intOrRealArray[i].i = tupleTmp(i);
  } else if tupleTmp(i).type == real {
    intOrRealArray[i].r = tupleTmp(i);
  } else {
    compilerError("unhandled type assigned to union IntOrReal");
  }
}`